# How to apply MUSIC to FMCW radar IF data?

Tags: radar, analog-to-digital, music, doa

I'm working on target extraction with raw FMCW ADC data. I arranged my received data in an (numADCsamples x numAntennas x numChirpsPerFrame) radar cube.

So far I am using range FFT and doppler FFT to generate range doppler map. Next I apply OS-CFAR for target extraction.
Using 3D-FFT on the extracted targets (numTargets x numAntennas)-array with zero-padding, I am able to obtain the angle information about the extracted targets.

Unfortunately, the angle-resolution is pretty bad, so I came across Multiple Signal Classification. Is there a way to implement MUSIC to (numTargets x numAntennas)-array, or do I have to use multiple snapshots? E.g. I could use (numChirpsPerFrame x numTargets x numAntennas)-array, but then I would not be able to obtain doppler-velocity anymore, if my understanding is correct.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you can show a minimum example or show your implementation.

Comment: Implementation is pretty similar to https://github.com/PreSenseRadar/OpenRadar/blob/master/demo/visualizer/main.py#L182 up to line 182, that's where I want to add the MUSIC implementation